# placing footer at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, positioning, footer

I have encountered an issue while trying to place the footer of my website at the bottom by using CSS. I have tried several methods found on the internet to fix this issue, but none of them worked. I tried to open a `div` with relative position and place my footer in it by using absolute positioning, though it again didn't work. Here is my code,

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 20px;

}

header {
 background-color: #292627;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 font-size: 2vmin;
 color: white;
 padding: 1%;
 position: relative;
 
}

#logo {

 height: 50%;
}
aside {
 position: relative;
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 20%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 margin: 0%;
 padding: 1%;
 float: left;
}

article {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 1%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 
}

footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0%;
 padding: 1%;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

#copyright {
 bottom: 0%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
  <title> AUFA projects</title>
  <script src = "script.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet_home.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <a href="http://aufaprojects.ml"> <img src="recources/aufa_proj.png" alt="AUFAprojects" id="logo"></a>
   <h1>AUFA Projects</h1>
  </header>
  <aside>
   <p>What you are looking for is Viewport Percentage Units: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

   The values are: ‘vw’ (viewport width), ‘vh’ (viewport height), ‘vmin’ (the smaller of vw or vh), ‘vmax’ (the larger or vw or vh).

   1 v == 1% of the initial containing block

   using it looks like this:

   p {font-size: 4vw;}

   As you can see, when the viewport widt</p>

  </aside>
  <article>
   <h1> About us </h1>
   <p>AUFA is a group of AUA students, who post their project, programs and other data in this website. You are allowed to use the content or modify it, however you should give credits in the following form
    "The original code was created by AUFA (aufaprojects.ml)"</p>
   
  </article>
  
  <footer>
    
   <p id = "copyright"> Copyright &#169; AUFA</p>

  </footer>  

 </body>


</html>
```

Please help to fix my issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Footer position should be absulote and body relative also absulote other tag under the body tag

Comment: Why not use fixed position? Are you looking to place it at the bottom of the viewport window or the bottom of your webpage

Comment: @devpro with absolute positioning it works only for a fixed screen. It stays at the same place while scrolling

Comment: @Adjit I don't want to use fixed positioning rather I want to place the footer at the bottom of the webpage

Comment: Yes @adjit is right position fixed or change as I suggest

Comment: Then you shouldn't need to do anything. Just make sure it is the last element of the dom tree, and that other container elements aren't positioned absolutely or fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple solution to your problem is by clearing the floated article just before the footer. Best solution is to include the following inside your style for the footer `clear: both;` as shown below:

```
footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is a very simple and effective solution

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look into using the sticky footer code on http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/.  It requires you to slightly restructure your code by creating a wrapper div around everything except for the footer and to add the following css code

```
{
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important; /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

This should do what you want.

Also, if you are using SASS Compass, you can check out the [sticky footer module](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/) which I use religiously to keep the footer at the bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from your original answer, and only changing 3 lines (I just wanted a quick demo for you to be able to look at).

This one change is to give the footer a fixed position instead of giving it an absolute or relative position. In your question you said you had wanted it on the bottom and giving the footer a fixed position, a 'bottom' value of 10px, and a 'right' value of 10px you're always assured that it is going to be in the bottom right hand corner of the screen.

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 20px;

}

header {
 background-color: #292627;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 font-size: 2vmin;
 color: white;
 padding: 1%;
 position: relative;
 
}

#logo {

 height: 50%;
}
aside {
 position: relative;
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 20%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 margin: 0%;
 padding: 1%;
 float: left;
}

article {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 1%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 
}

footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right:10px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

#copyright {
 bottom: 0%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
  <title> AUFA projects</title>
  <script src = "script.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet_home.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <a href="http://aufaprojects.ml"> <img src="recources/aufa_proj.png" alt="AUFAprojects" id="logo"></a>
   <h1>AUFA Projects</h1>
  </header>
  <aside>
   <p>What you are looking for is Viewport Percentage Units: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

   The values are: ‘vw’ (viewport width), ‘vh’ (viewport height), ‘vmin’ (the smaller of vw or vh), ‘vmax’ (the larger or vw or vh).

   1 v == 1% of the initial containing block

   using it looks like this:

   p {font-size: 4vw;}

   As you can see, when the viewport widt</p>

  </aside>
  <article>
   <h1> About us </h1>
   <p>AUFA is a group of AUA students, who post their project, programs and other data in this website. You are allowed to use the content or modify it, however you should give credits in the following form
    "The original code was created by AUFA (aufaprojects.ml)"</p>
   
  </article>
  
  <footer>
    
   <p id = "copyright"> Copyright &#169; AUFA</p>

  </footer>  

 </body>


</html>
```

#### Update

I just saw in the comments of your question that you don't want to use a fixed position.

Please consider the following:

```css
body {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
    padding:0; 
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 20px;

}

header {
 background-color: #292627;
 width: 100%;
    height:40%;
 font-size: 2vmin;
 color: white;
 padding: 1%;
 position: relative;
 
}

#logo {

 height: 50%;
}
aside {
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 20%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 margin: 0%;
 padding: 1%;
 float: left;
}

article {
 float: right;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 1%;
 font-size: 3vmin;
}

footer {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

#copyright {
 bottom: 0%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3vmin;
 color: red;
}
.aside-article-wrapper{
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
.bottom {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
  <title> AUFA projects</title>
  <script src = "script.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet_home.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <a href="http://aufaprojects.ml"> <img src="recources/aufa_proj.png" alt="AUFAprojects" id="logo"></a>
   <h1>AUFA Projects</h1>
  </header>
        <section class="aside-article-wrapper">
       <aside>
   <p>What you are looking for is Viewport Percentage Units: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

   The values are: ‘vw’ (viewport width), ‘vh’ (viewport height), ‘vmin’ (the smaller of vw or vh), ‘vmax’ (the larger or vw or vh).

   1 v == 1% of the initial containing block

   using it looks like this:

   p {font-size: 4vw;}

   As you can see, when the viewport widt</p>

      </aside>
    <article>
   <h1> About us </h1>
   <p>AUFA is a group of AUA students, who post their project, programs and other data in this website. You are allowed to use the content or modify it, however you should give credits in the following form
    "The original code was created by AUFA (aufaprojects.ml)"</p>
   
    </article>
  </section>
  <footer>
    
   <p id = "copyright"> Copyright &#169; AUFA</p>

  </footer>  

 </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative property to html tag and position absolute to footer as shown below and footer, this will always make element with class "footer" at the bottom of page content

```css
html {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}

.footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
```